# Disappearing navpoints

Tags: eclipse, tooltwist

I edited my navpoints from within the ToolTwist workbench, and after restarting the server all my navpoints had disappeared. I've checked the navpoint file, and it looks to be correct. I've tried restarting the server, but still ALL the navpoints have disappeared.

Can anybody tell me what I've done wrong, or suggest something to try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally there is no need to edit the navpoint definition files - the navpoint tab in the Designer should be used. If for some reason it does need to be edited, make sure you restart the server immediately after making the changes or else they may be overwritten by the Designer.
Make sure that the encoding for the file is correct. The navpoint allows multi-lingual descriptions, SEO fields, etc, so needs to be stored as Unicode.

To check this, right click on the file in the Workbench (e.g. webdesign/myproject/navpoints/myproject.xml) and select properties. On the Resource tab, you'll see a section titled "Text file encoding". The correct value for this is UTF-16